# React-virtualized List scroll going crazy and Autosizer doesn't work

Tags: react-virtualized

The scroll of the list is going crazy when I scroll and it keeps jittering afterwards even if I don't do anything) as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNNL3.jpg (sorry embedding that gif doesn't work here)

I made a minimal example where it happens in:

https://codesandbox.io/s/4r2q3omv1w

I did pass the style to the rows.

Also, if you change the height and width of the list to get the values from Autosizer, then the list doesn't appear, even though this looks exactly like in the [example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/List/List.example.js).

Any ideas how to fix these two problems?

EDIT: it seems that it works a little better in Firefox, still a little jumpy in my own code though and the codesandbox's scroll still isn't perfect. (it's super jumpy in chrome, even in incognito).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem was related to 2 issues:

- Not delegating `height` and `width` from `<AutoSizer>` to the `<List>`
- Row height was defined as `50` but the actual rendered height was more -

  > From the [docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md#examples): *Note that it is very important that rows do not have vertical overflow. It would make scrolling the list difficult (as individual items will intercept the scroll events)*

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jppm1mmo83